# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gmail

our Rails 3.2 application's "resend activation code" mail feature was working until the code was transferred from the previous developer to us. Now we get this error

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in UsersController#create
```

Our mail settings remain untouched like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
:address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",  
:port                 => 587,  
:domain               => "example.com",  
:user_name            => "username",  
:password             => "password",  
:authentication       => "plain",  
:enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

We are somehow not able to figure it out as to why the email stop's working.
We have checked the gmail server also responding back to us via telnet.
We have also enabled the Less Secure Apps feature of Gmail's in Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us all your config.action_mailer. delivery_method, default_url_options, perform_deliveries, raise_delivery_errors etc ...   and show your mail.log if you can go /var/log/mail.log.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using Gmail's settings, I'd say you should try this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 address: "smtp.gmail.com",
 port: 587,
 user_name: ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
 password: ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
 authentication: :plain,
 enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

If you're using Sendgrid, as above you should have something like:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    domain: 'heroku.com', #for your helo domain
    address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: 587,
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Don't forget to define your `ENV` variables appropriately. 
You can find [more discussion around this here](https://launchschool.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails)